# Position menu in maps

Tags: flutter, widget

Does someone know which widget i could use in Flutter to build a window that appears on the bottom of a page and shows some informations on the selected position like in Google Maps. It would be even  better with the draggable feature to reveal more details. Thanks

[image: et,]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the [Show Modal Bottom Sheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) feature for the first section of your question.